How to use @TempDir with JUnit 5 @ParameterizedTest to create a separate temporary directory for each test?
I am using JUnit 5's @ParameterizedTest annotation to run tests with different inputs, and I want to generate a separate temporary directory for each test. Here's how my code looks:
class MyTestClass {

    static Stream<Arguments> syntax() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of("grammars/Simple.g4", "expr"),
            Arguments.of("grammars/Arithmetic.g4", "prog")
        );
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("syntax")
    void checksSyntax(
        @TempDir final Path temp,  // Temporary directory created by JUnit
        final String name,
        final String rule
    ) {     
        // some testing logic   
    }
}


The method syntax() provides different inputs to the test, and I want to ensure that each test run has its own temporary directory.
However, when I run the code, I get the following exception:
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: 
Discovered multiple competing ParameterResolvers for parameter [java.nio.file.Path arg0] 
in method [void checksSyntax(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]:
org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TempDirectory@4ae3c1cd,
org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestParameterResolver@29f69090

I tried modifying the code by passing the temporary directory from the method source:
static Stream<Arguments> syntax(@TempDir final Path temp) {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(temp, "grammars/Simple.g4", "expr"),
        Arguments.of(temp, "grammars/Arithmetic.g4", "prog")
    );
}

However, this results in using the same temporary directory for all test cases, which is not what I want. I need a separate temporary directory for each test case.
Question:
How can I ensure that a new temporary directory is created for each test case in a JUnit 5 @ParameterizedTest? What is the proper way to integrate @TempDir with parameterized tests without causing conflicts with JUnit's parameter resolvers?

Workaround
Place @TempDir parameter last.
I've discovered a simple workaround that achieves the desired result with a minor adjustment. The issue seems to arise due to the order of parameters in the test method. By changing the parameter order from Path, String, String to String, String, Path (where Path represents the temporary directory) JUnit will no longer throw exceptions.
Placing the Path parameter last ensures that the method works as expected. This might be because JUnit processes @TempDir parameters differently when placed at the end of the parameter list.
Here’s a working example:
class MyTestClass {

    static Stream<Arguments> syntax() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of("grammars/Simple.g4", "expr"),
            Arguments.of("grammars/Arithmetic.g4", "prog")
        );
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("syntax")
    void checksSyntax(
        final String name,
        final String rule
        @TempDir final Path temp,  // Temporary directory created by JUnit
    ) {     
        // some testing logic   
    }
}

